# place markers stores(pirtucular store name) with google maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-maps

Hi I want place markers on all shoppers stop stores which are near to user current location. I am using following code

currently I am getting only 2 locations, I want set some radius and want to display all the stores also.

```
    private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>> {

    @Override
    protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
        // Creating an instance of Geocoder class
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {
            // Getting a maximum of 3 Address that matches the input text
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 10);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return addresses;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) {

        if(addresses==null || addresses.size()==0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Clears all the existing markers on the map
        googleMap.clear();

        // Adding Markers on Google Map for each matching address
        for(int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++){

            Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);

            // Creating an instance of GeoPoint, to display in Google Map
            latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

            String addressText = String.format("%s, %s",
                    address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                    address.getCountryName());

            markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title(addressText);

            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            // Locate the first location
            if(i==0)
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        }
    }
}
```

but unable to get relevant results. Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at [nearby search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) of Places API web service.

To make your life easier you can also use the Java Client for Google Maps Services located at github:

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java

Follow documentation of the Java Client library and you should be able to search nearby places for given location and radius.

I hope this helps!